# Preview Pictures in Windows 10

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-10

Just upgraded to Windows 10. My wife wants to preview pictures the way she did in earlier Windows versions, i.e. right-clicking on the icon or filename and selecting "Preview". Well, the new version of Windows Explorer doesn't have this on the pop-up menu anymore. Any ideas?

Comment: I have Preview on Windows 10. [As seen here](http://i.imgur.com/JFnD5Y0.png).

Comment: Duplicate of [Windows Photo viewer](http://superuser.com/posts/comments/1307894)?

Comment: MrStatic - That's interesting. My pop-up looks just like yours, except for "Open" vs "Preview". The files are all jpegs and pngs, so I don't think it's anything too weird there. Hmmm.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on photo, select "Open With", select "Windows Photo Viewer".

8/17/15  I have discovered that "Windows Photo Viewer" is not available in my Insiders Preview Version of W10, Build 10240.  However, it is available in my upgrade versions of W10 Home and W10 Pro.  I know I used the program in the previous versions, so it must have survived the updates to W10.  A very similar program is included in the "Windows Live" set of programs, called "Windows Live Photo Gallery".  Installing "...Photo Gallery" adds a right click function very similar to the original "Windows Photo Viewer".

Comment: Gary Clemens and gwc: If you are the same person, it would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts.  You should use the [contact form](http://superuser.com/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles” to have your accounts merged.  In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts.  For your information, these are http://superuser.com/users/484177/gary-clemens and http://superuser.com/users/484226/gwc.  You’ll then be able to [edit] your answer.